# D3 Number Format with Using HTML Unicode Expressions

Tags: javascript, d3.js, unicode

i'm working on an application and i am using D3 Treemaps, i have loaded my data but i'm having problems with the number format and the currency type.. i am a nigerian so the unicode expression for our currency, "Naira" is ₦ (`&#8358`);

```
 var defaults = {
      margin: {top: 24, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0},
      rootname: "TOP",
      format: ("₦,.3f"),  //- and not working
      title: "",
      width: 765,
      height: 450
  };
```

the above example does not work because d3 does not recognize the character except if the unicode expression is used.

what i want my output as this - ₦345,456,678

but i cant seem to get it right... i have gone through all the custom formatters example and other available examples online, but cant seem to get it done..

i got different available examples on this site, but applying it is the issue. http://koaning.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/html/d3format.html.

thanks.

Comment: okay.. i'd do that now... thanks...

Answer (score 2):

The dollar `$` sign is only to tell d3 that you are using a currency. To change the currency symbol, you can define a custom locale with [d3.formatLocale()](https://github.com/d3/d3-format#formatLocale).

The `currency` property can be used to specify the symbols by using a 2 positions array for the symbol before and after the number. In your case it would be `currency: ["₦", ""]`.

Here is a working snippet:

```js
var amount = 123456789.1234;

var locale = d3.formatLocale({
  decimal: ".",
  thousands: ",",
  grouping: [3],
  currency: ["₦", ""]
});

var f = locale.format("$,.2f");

d3.select("#amount").text(f(amount));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Number: <span id="amount"></span>
</div>
```